# Getting dnu build working on TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, asp.net-core, dnx, teamcity-9.0

We're trying to get a vNext project building on TeamCity 9.16 - the project is using the dnx451 and dnxcore50 frameworks.

When TeamCity is running `dnu build` for DNX,Version=v4.5.1 it's erroring when trying to build `System.Configuration 4.0.0` with the following error:

```
DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0012: The type 'Action<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes
```

However running `dnu build` from the command line when logged on to the machine as the TeamCity build agent is successful (after running `dnvm upgrade`)

I suspect that this might be something to do with TeamCity and Paths but am at a loss as how to proceed.

Comment: Is the TeamCity agent running under a user or system account?

Comment: The TeamCity agent is running under a service account

Comment: Can you try to run it under a regular user account? We (the asp.net team) use TeamCity for our builds and everything runs under a user account

Comment: Or compare the paths of the two user accounts :)

Comment: Bingo! Victor running the build agent as a user account and adding the appropriate paths worked. Thank you.